# How does SQL process "wrapped joins"?

Tags: sql

I'm going through some older code, and one query is laid out in the following manner:

```
FROM (A INNER JOIN (B LEFT JOIN C ON B.ID2 = C.ID2) ON A.ID1= B.ID1)
```

I'm confused as to how this would actually be processed? What's the difference between the above and below?

```
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.ID1 = B.ID1
LEFT JOIN C on B.ID2 = C.ID2
```

Comment: As far as I know, an inner join creates a virtual 'table' that the select statement operates on. (That's not the best way to put it but it makes sense to me.) Anyways B LEFT JOIN C creates a table interface with all the cols of B and C for you to query off of, then you join that interface to A. I doubt there's a real difference

Comment: Look at the explain plan for both.

Comment: I am curious to know if your results differ.  I suspect they will be the same, perhaps with a slight variation in performance, possibly.

Comment: The query optimizer will determine the join ordering, if you are not selecting any columns from the outer-join then it will be omitted completely. The answer, of course, is to test each.

Comment: In SQL, you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*. Provided two SQL  statements are *logically* asking for the same result, unless the optimizer is having an off day, they should produce the *same* query plan. It thus matter far less about how you structure your query; You should (as with most languages) strive to make it most readable for future maintainers.

Answer (score 0):

The first code uses subquery. I used the Northwind data base to test this if both codes produce the same results.

I first used the first query:

```
Select *
From(Categories c JOIN (Products p Left Join Suppliers s on p.SupplierID=s.SupplierID) on c.CategoryID=p.CategoryID)
```

Then I used the following query:

```
Select * 
From Categories c
Join Products p on c.CategoryID=p.CategoryID
Left Join Suppliers s on p.SupplierID=s.SupplierID
```

It seems they produce the exact same result. Furthermore, in both queries I changed Inner Join with Left Join and and Left Join with Inner join. And I tested it and they seem to give same results. So I think they are the same.